# Python Qt6 QTableView - Iterate Column and Value

Tags: python, pyqt6

I have a QTableView object that is successfully displaying data as expected. When the user clicks on a cell it automatically selects the entire row without any problems. What I would like to do is display the column name and cell value for the selected row (e.g. iterate the row), which will feed into a new QTableView (basically want to transpose the selected row for easier viewing).

I've read through simpler examples and gone through the QT documentation but really struggling to get this working. I can retrieve the cell value but not the column name.

```
self.tblView = QTableView()
```

```
self.tblModel = TableModel(data)
self.tblModel.layoutChanged.emit()
self.tblView.setModel(self.tblModel)
self.tblView.selectRow(0)
self.tblView.clicked.connect(self.qTableViewSingleRowSelection)
```

```
def qTableViewSingleRowSelection(self, clickedIndex):
   row = clickedIndex.row()
   column = clickedIndex.column()
   print("Selected Row: {0}".format(row))
   print("Selected Column: {0}".format(column))
   self.tblView.selectRow(row)
```

I haven't included the code that didn't work but all I want is to return a dictionary object that contains {'Column 1' : 'Value 1'} etc. for only the selected row. Seems so simple yet really struggling to get this working. Really appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this

```
class YourClass():
    ...
    self.dictionary = {}
    ...
    def qTableViewSingleRowSelection(self, clickedIndex):
        ...
        model = self.tblView.model()
        value = model.data(model.index(row,column), Qt.DisplayRole)
        header = model.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole)
        self.dictionary[header] = value
```

Anyway, everytime you select an item of a column where you already selected an item, you will subscribe that item.
exemple:

```
Table:
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
```

If you select `a` and then you select `e`, your dictonary will be `{1:'a',2:'e'}`, but whe you select `d`, your dictonary will be `{1:'d',2:'e'}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but this is how I overcome the problem in the end.

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    ...

    def rowRecord(self, index):
        column = str(self._data.columns[index.column()])
        value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
        return column, value

class Metadata(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    ...

    def qTableViewSingleRowSelection(self, clickedIndex):
        row = clickedIndex.row()
        self.tblView.selectRow(row)
        columns = self.tblModel.columnCount(None)
        row_dictionary = {}
        for columnIndex in range(columns):
            column, value = self.tblModel.rowRecord(self.tblModel.index(row, columnIndex))
            if(str(value).strip() != ""):
                row_dictionary[column] = (value)
        self.dataframe_record = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(row_dictionary,orient='index')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).